# Is connected forest a spanning tree?

Tags: graphs, terminology

> forest : set of disjoint trees.

So a connected forest is a forest, a tree, a spanning forest and a spanning tree.

Is that correct?

Edit: disjoint trees in the forest are connected by single edge, so as to make the forest connected

Comment: Depends on how you connect them. Whether it's spanning is independent of that.

Comment: Which graph is it spanning? A spanning tree is always a spanning tree *of some graph*.

Answer (score 2):

A connected forest is a tree (as well as a forest).

The terms *spanning forest* and *spanning tree* refer to an ambient graph. Given a connected graph $G$, a *spanning tree* is a subset of the edges of $G$ (spanning all vertices) which forms a tree. Similarly, if $G$ is a graph with $c$ connected components, then a *spanning forest* is a subset of the edges of $G$ (spanning all vertices) which is a disjoint union of $c$ trees.